# php script stops right after a simple return statement

Tags: php, return

Hello fellow programmers,

I have made a function that looks up the database if a login already exists and then returns either true or false, here is the body of this function:

```
public static function loginExiste($login)
{
    $cnx = new GestionBD("localhost", "fnak", "root", "");

    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);

    $ret = $cnx->execRequete("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE Client_Login = '".$login."'");

    $col = mysql_fetch_array($ret);
    echo 2;
    if ($col[0] > 0)
    {
        echo 3;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 4;
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is how I call this function:

```
echo 1;
if (!ExecRequete::loginExiste($_POST['login']))
{
    echo 5;
    /*
    echo '<center><p style="color:red;">
                Erreur: Login existe déjà
            </p></center>';
    exit();
    */
}
echo 6;
```

Now as you can see, I have some echo statements scattered around to see how the execution is flowing. The result I get every single time is this:

if the login exists: 123
if it doesn't exist: 124

From the result I see that the script stops the execution right after the return statement. normally It should be like this:

1236 or 12456

The worst part about this is that it happened to me during an exam, that made me very upset as it doesn't make sense at all. The debugging lost me so much time that I couldn't finish the other easy parts..

Can anybody see why is this strange behavior happening here ?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your logic, but it's possible PHP is emiting an error that isn't being displayed.  Is error_reporting and display_errors/log_errors configured?  BTW, bit of advice regarding exam technique.  If you find you're bogging down on something, leave it and come back to it later.  Provided you get answers down they'll be marked, it doesn't matter if they're not in order.

Comment: yeh I already added the instructions: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); in the functions script and in the main one. I also took the function out of the class and put it in the same script, and I tried using a global variable to output the value but the execution never goes beyond the function..

Comment: There's always [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [zend debugger](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Installation-Guide.pdf) to track down spurious issues like this.

Comment: Why dont you try using try/catch block like this try{ //supicious code } catch (Exception $e) { $e->getMessage(); }

Comment: well I already tried the Try/catch block around the function.. didn't do the trick.. what's left for me is to use xdebug, but I need to install it and know how to use it with netbeans..

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST['login'] is actually set? try this isset($_POST['login']) and if returns true than call the loginExiste function

Comment: try using separate variable, like this $newVar = ExecRequete::loginExiste($_POST['login'])  and than try if(!$newVar)

Comment: for $_POST['login'] I did use isset on it before, all of that code is inside an if statement testing the presence of that variable. And from my result it's clear that $_POST['login'] is defined as the output changes when I give an existing or a non-existing login. For the seperate variable I did try it.. but the execution doesn't get out of the function so that I get the return value in the main script, I wrote: $t = loginExiste($_POST['login']); echo "'".$t."'"; and it didn't output anything no matter if the login exists or not, not even the quotes '' !

Comment: Have you checked the apache error log for any messages? On one occasion something in a script I was writing was making Apache crash and automatically restart and you could only see it in the server log files.

Comment: no, the logs I checked on wamp (apache, php and mysql) don't contain any thing related to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally ! I got where the error was ^^

after restarting the function from scratch (like using *if ($login == "a") return true;*) I found out that the problem was in the destructor of my GestionBD class that handles the connection with mysql. Because all the code in the function worked except at the very end on the return statement.

What made me sure it was the destructor, is when I put *$cnx = null;* before my *echo 2;* and the execution stopped before the echo. Then I commented out the destructor and everything worked as needed. but I wondered what was wrong in my destructor...

Here's how it looked:

```
function __destruct()
{
    @mysql_close($this->$connexion);
}
```

Now, if anyone is familiar with OOP in PHP, he will spot the error right away.. the variable connexion is a member variable in the class. So when we refer to it with the pointer $this we needed to put it without $ (ahh I hate you $, I either forget you or put when you're not needed :/ )

the correct destructor is this:

```
function __destruct()
{
    @mysql_close($this->connexion);
}
```

but this mysql_close function is certainly not that well made, it doesn't give any error message, not any exception, it just crashes the engine and leaves you wondering why ..

Thank you all for your answers and help, it's really appreciated :) and an advice for everyone is that if you get any strange behavior or error messages at a simple *return true;* check all you local object's destructors.. they may be guilty, and also <del>USE PDO</del> don't use `@` with mysql functions when debugging as it supresses any error output ;)

Comment: you may want to remove `@` on mysql_close so that it will not suppress the error specially during debugging or development. upvote on the answer downvote on the question as the question does not lead to the answer. The error is found on `GestionBD` and not in the code provided